# ArrayList: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

I still have the problem when i try to add person. The code is suppose to detect invalid name and birthday, and would not to add this person into the personList. However, because i'm not able to get the birthday until the code read it, the person object can only be added when the loop finished. The problem occurs when i try to test to add an invlid person name and/or birthday. It shows:

Failed to add person: Invalid name!!

New record:

Name: null"

Birthday: Unkown DOB

has been added!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Instruction.readInstruction(Instruction.java:272) 
at EPB.main(EPB.java:12)





else if(words[0].equalsIgnoreCase("add"))
                {   
                    Person p = new Person();

                    String s1 = line.substring(words[0].length()).trim();
                    String[] s2 = s1.split(";");
                    if(s2.length>=2)// s2[0] = " name Testing Three" s2[1] = " birthday 13-05-1981" and s2[2]=" address.."
                    {
                        for(int i=0; i<s2.length;i++)
                        {
                            String s3 = s2[i].trim(); // "delete the leading space" s2[0] = "name Testing Three" s2[1] = "birthday 13-05-1981"
                            String[] s4 = s3.split("\\s+"); //s4[0] = name; s4[1] = Testing; s4[2]=Three 


                            if(s4.length>=2) // s2[1]=birthday 13-05-1986 only has length of 2
                            {
                                if(s4[0].equalsIgnoreCase("name"))
                                {
                                        //System.out.println(s4[1]);
                                    String name="";
                                    if(Functions.nameValidation(s4[1]))
                                    {
                                        for(int j=2;j<s4.length;j++)
                                        {
                                            name = s4[1] + " " + s4[j];
                                        }
                                        if(Functions.nameValidation(name))
                                        {
                                            p.setName(name);
                                        }
                                        else                                                
                                        {
                                            System.out.println("Failed to add person: Invalid name!");
                                            break;
                                        }

                                    }                                           
                                    else
                                    {
                                        System.out.println("Failed to add person: Invalid name!!");
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }//end of word equals to name
                                    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
                                else if(s4[0].equalsIgnoreCase("birthday") && s4.length ==2)
                                {
                                    if(Functions.dateValidation(s4[1]))
                                    {
                                        try 
                                        {
                                            p.setBirthdayString(s4[1]);
                                        } 
                                        catch (ParseException e) 
                                        {
                                                //e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        System.out.println("Failed to add person: Invalid Birthday Format");
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                    //end of word equals to birthday
                                    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
                        boolean notFound = false;
                        for(Person p1: personList)
                        {
                            if(p1.getName().equals(p.getName()))
                            {
                                if(p1.getBirthdayString().equals(p.getBirthdayString()))    
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Information in record" +"\n" + "name: "+ p.getName() + "\n" + "Birthday: " + p.getBirthdayString() + "\n" +"has been updated");
                                    p1.setEmail(p.getEmail());
                                    p1.setPhone(p.getPhone());
                                    p1.setAddress(p.getAddress());

                                    notFound = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (!notFound)
                        {
                            if(Functions.nameValidation(p.getName()) && Functions.dateValidation(p.getBirthdayString()))
                            {
                                System.out.println("New record: " +"\n"+"Name: " + p.getName() + "\""+ "\n"+ "Birthday: " + p.getBirthdayString() + "\nhas been added!");
                                    personList.add(p);

                            }
                            FileIO.outData(personList, outputFileName);     
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                }
```

Comment: In future, please try to narrow your problem down to a *short* but complete program demonstrating the problem. You've given a lot of code here, most of which is irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what to meant to do in that final loop instead of iterating over `personList` and checking at each step if it contains the name and the birthday of `p`, was to check this condition for each element in the iteration kind of like this:

```
p1.getName().equals(p.getName())
```

instead of `personList.contains(p.getName())`

and

```
p1.getBirthdayString().equals(p.getBirthdayString())
```

instead of `personList.contains(p.getBirthdayString())`

This would fix the logic bug, and also the exception, since you won't be calling `contains` while iterating through the collection.

Edit:
Then you would still have a bug where you're trying to add `p` to `personList` in that same loop (in the "else" block: `personList.add(p)`). The way you're doing it now is not only getting you an exception, but it's trying to add person `p` for each `p1` in the list that's not equal to it. To fix this you would need to keep a boolean inside the loop that checks if any matches were found (true if any of the conditions above for p1 is ever checked), and add `p` to `personList` outsite the loop, if said boolean is not true.

In conclusion, this is the modified code for the iterating loop:

```java
boolean found = false;
for(Person p1: personList)
        {
            if(p1.getName.equals(p.getName()))
            {
                if(p1.getBirthdayString.equals(p.getBirthdayString()))                            
                {
                    System.out.println("Information in record" +"\n" + "name: "+ p.getName() + "\n" + "Birthday: " + p.getBirthdayString() + "\n" +"has been updated");
                    p1.setEmail(p.getEmail());
                    p1.setPhone(p.getPhone());
                    p1.setAddress(p.getAddress());
                    FileIO.outData(personList, outputFileName);

                    found = true;
                 }

            }

        }
if (!found)
{
        System.out.println("New record has been added!");
        personList.add(p);
        FileIO.outData(personList, outputFileName); 
}
```

Comment: you are exactly right. You did a very great help. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8):

This is the problem:

```
for(Person p1: personList)
{
    ...
    personList.add(p);
}
```

You can't modify a collection while you're iterating over it. The simplest fix is probably to have a *separate* list which you build up while you iterate over `personList`, then add everything to it later:

```
List<Person> newPeople = new ArrayList<Person>();
for(Person p1: personList)
{
    ...
    newPeople.add(p);
}
personList.addAll(newPeople);
```

(As Peter points out, you may well not want to add this *anyway* - but that's why you're getting the exception.)

Comment: +0 Most likely the original code is completely wrong.  The person being added is already in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over personList and checking if this list contains Name and BirthdayString values. This does not make sense because this list contains only Person objects.

And your problem is that you add new object to this list when iterating if contains check fails, this causes exception:

```
System.out.println("New record has been added!");
personList.add(p);
```

Basically you need to rethink your contains checks and not modify collection you are iterating.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is you have no idea where to look.  You have a problem here

```
                    for(Person p1: personList)
                    {
                        if(personList.contains(p.getName()))
                        {
                            if(!personList.contains(p.getBirthdayString()))
                            {
                                    System.out.println("New record has been added!");
                                    personList.add(p);
```

You are modifying you list while iterating over it.

Most likely this is a bug, rather than something you should do another way.